# MS Active Directory and non-member authentication

Tags: authentication, active-directory

I have a Java application that authenticates against Active Directory. When running the program on a machine that is part of the domain, the application is successfully able to authenticate. When executed on the server however, the authentication fails.

Is there a way from Active Directory to block LDAP authentication from non-domain machines? If there is, is it an "all or nothing" setting or can it be configured with certain exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to enable the anonymous queries.See [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320528)

PS: this wouldn't be good from a security point of view.